# Load additional window, run code when it's loaded

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

i'm trying to open a new window, and when it's opened I want to run more code to populate a TreeView. I want to do it from the command so I don't need to add any code behind the window.

Here is my command:

**Classes > Commands.cs**

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Command: SelectFolder
        /// </summary>
        #region SelectFolder
        public static RoutedUICommand SelectFolder
        {
            get { return _SelectFolder; }
        }
        public static void SelectFolder_Executed(object sender,
                   ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Window FolderDialog = new Views.FolderExplorer();
            FolderDialog.Show();

            //Bind Commands
            Classes.MyCommands.BindCommandsToWindow(FolderDialog);

            FolderDialog.ContentRendered += Functions.LoadFolderTree();
        }
        public static void SelectFolder_CanExecute(object sender,
                           CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            e.CanExecute = true;
        }
        #endregion
```

Getting this error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'System.EventHandler'
>
> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or
>   property 'Functions.LoadFolderTree()'

At the moment i'm trying to run a function which will then populate the TreeView, but if there is a good way to do it from within the Command instead of needing an additional function then please say. This is my current code:

**Classes > Functions.cs**

```
namespace Duplicate_Deleter.Classes
{
    class Functions
    {
        public void LoadFolderTree()
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Hello");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There are 2 problems:**

1) Your LoadFolderTree function has the wrong signature: no arguments instead of the typical sender/Eventargs arguments for an eventhandler

2) You need a Functions object to call a non-static method

**Possible fixes:**

1) Make the function static and add the correct arguments

```
public class Functions
{
    public static void LoadFolderTree(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Hello");
    }
}
```

2) Call the function from an instance of Functions and add the correct arguments

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var f = new Functions();
        ContentRendered += f.LoadFolderTree;
    }
}

public class Functions
{
    public  void LoadFolderTree(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Hello");
    }
}
```

3)Best way: Simply add the default eventhandler. Type "ContentendRendered +=" and then press "tab" twice to automatically add the correct eventhandler

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ContentRendered += MainWindow_ContentRendered;
    }

    void MainWindow_ContentRendered(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Hello");
    }
```